# New Window wxWidgets

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I really did search a lot before ask this question. Sorry if it's a simple question.

In my wxWidgets app, I want to new a `wxHtmlWindow` from a menu choice. (I've already got my main app window showed up correctly).

I set up `EVENT_TABLE` :

```
EVT_MENU(wxID_HELP, MyFrame::OnHelp)
```

and then the Function (I got a pointer html_help in the class private):

```
void MyFrame::OnHelp(wxCommandEvent& event)
// Callback for the Help menu item
{
    cout << "Enter OnHelp" << endl;
    wxWindow* help_win = new wxWindow(NULL, -1, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 600));
    cout << "New window" << endl;
    help_win->Show(true);
    cout << "Show" << endl;
    html_help = new wxHtmlWindow(help_win, -1);
    cout << "After new" << endl;
    wxString m_Name = wxT("help.html");
    //SetTopWindow(html_help);
    bool hel = html_help->LoadPage(m_Name);
    cout << "After Loadpage" << endl;
}
```

Sorry for the couts. The program throw out segmentation fault after new htmlwindow.

The first time I tried is just new `wxHtmlWindow(NULL)` with no other wxWindows, but seems not working, the `->LoadPage` has segfault . Then I tried `new wxHtmlWindow(this)`, the `htmlwindow` showed on current window, not I want .

You may just ignore all the codes, and tell me how to new a wxHtmlWindow (maybe in a new frame? or not) and can actually do the LoadPage work.

Thank you very much!

BTW, I'm using 2.812 wxWidgets, with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxWindow` is a base class for all the other widgets, there are rare occasions when you need to and can use it directly.

For your case you need a top-level window (that is a `wxFrame` or `wxDialog`) as the parent for your `wxHtmlWindow`. And BTW, only top-level windows can have `NULL` parent.

To load the html you would probably do better with `html_help->LoadFile(wxFileName("help.html"))`. The docs are online for both functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know the difference between these before. I'll try to use wxDialog then.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in a solitaire game program for Windows.

Don't know how portable or general this code is.

The program is in a state of demonstration-of-principle, so this code is also not very clean or generalized, only what I needed.

```
#pragma once
// Copyright © 2014 Alf P. Steinbach.

// DEBUG:
#include <thisApp/cppx/trace_stream.h>
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

//#include <thisApp/ie/css3_support.h>        // ie::Css3_support
#include <thisApp/wxx/underscore_macro.h>   // _

#include <wx/filesys.h>             // wxFileSystem
#include <wx/fs_mem.h>              // wxMemoryFSHandler
#include <wx/dialog.h>              // wxDialog
#include <wx/sizer.h>               // wxBoxSizer
//#include <wx/html/htmlwin.h>    // wxHtmlWindow
#include <wx/webview.h>             // wxWebView, wxWebViewEvent
#include <wx/webviewfshandler.h>    // wxWebViewFSHandler
#include <wx/statline.h>            // wxStaticLine
#include <wx/button.h>              // wxButton
#include <wx/utils.h>               // wxMilliSleep, wxLaunchDefaultBrowser

#include <thisApp/wxx/Named_bitmap.h>


namespace wxx {
    using cppx::trace_stream;
    using std::endl;

    class Html_dialog
        : public wxDialog
    {
    public:
        struct Args
        {
            wxWindow*       parent  = nullptr;
            wxWindowID      id      = wxID_ANY;
            wxString        title   = "";
            wxPoint         pos     = wxDefaultPosition;
            wxSize          size    = wxDefaultSize;
            long            style   = wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER;
            wxString        name    = wxDialogNameStr;

            Args() {}
        };

        Html_dialog( Args const& args = Args() )
            : wxDialog(
                args.parent, args.id, args.title, args.pos,
                args.size, args.style, args.name
                )
        {}
    };

    inline
    void show_dialog(
        wxWindow* const             parent,
        wxString const&             title,
        wxString const&             html,
        wxSize const&               size            = wxSize(380, 160),
        Named_bitmap const* const   p_first_bitmap  = nullptr,
        int const                   n_bitmaps       = 0
        )
    {
        wxFileSystem::AddHandler( new wxMemoryFSHandler );
        for( auto p = p_first_bitmap; p != p_first_bitmap + n_bitmaps; ++p )
        {
            wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile( p->filename, p->bitmap, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG );
        }

        static char const* const utf8_bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

        char const* const   html_cstr   = (
            html.StartsWith( utf8_bom )? html.c_str() + 3 : html.c_str()
            );
        trace_stream << "------------------------------------" << endl;
        trace_stream << html_cstr << endl;
        trace_stream << "------------------------------------" << endl;
        wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile( "dialog.htm", html_cstr );

        //wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile( "dialog.htm", "<html><body>Bah</body></html>" );
        Html_dialog::Args args;
        args.parent = parent;
        args.title = "About";
        Html_dialog dlg( args );

        wxWebView* browser = wxWebView::New(
            &dlg, wxID_ANY, wxWebViewDefaultURLStr,
            wxDefaultPosition, size
            );
        browser->RegisterHandler(
            wxSharedPtr<wxWebViewHandler>( new wxWebViewFSHandler( "memory" ) )
            );
        browser->LoadURL( "memory:dialog.htm" );
        //browser->SetPage( "<html><body>Bah</body></html>", "memory:dialog.htm" );
        dlg.SetLabel( title );

        struct WcEvent
        {
            static void handler (wxWebViewEvent& event)
            {
                wxString const url = event.GetURL();
                //wxMessageBox( url, "Navigation to:" );
                if( !url.StartsWith( "memory:" ) )
                {
                    event.Veto();
                    wxLaunchDefaultBrowser( url, wxBROWSER_NEW_WINDOW );
                }
            }
        };
        browser->Bind( wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, &WcEvent::handler );

        auto* const sizer = new wxGridSizer( 0 ) ;
        sizer->Add( browser, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0);
//        sizer->Add( browser, 1, wxALL, 10);
//        sizer->Add( new wxStaticLine( &dlg, -1 ), 0, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT, 10 );
//        sizer->Add( new wxButton( &dlg, wxID_OK, "Ok" ), 0, wxALL | wxALIGN_RIGHT, 15 );
        dlg.SetAutoLayout( true );
        dlg.SetSizer( sizer );
        sizer->Fit( &dlg );
        //dlg.Centre();
        dlg.SetLayoutAdaptationMode( wxDIALOG_ADAPTATION_MODE_DISABLED );
        dlg.ShowModal();

        wxMemoryFSHandler::RemoveFile( "dialog.htm" );
        for( auto p = p_first_bitmap; p != p_first_bitmap + n_bitmaps; ++p )
        {
            wxMemoryFSHandler::RemoveFile( p->filename );
        }
    }

}  // namespace wxx
```